# Different training result obtained from training simple LSTM in Keras and Pytorch

Tags: keras, nlp, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I’m trying to implement my LSTM model from Keras to Pytorch, but the results in Pytorch seem really bad at the moment. The network is really simple as below.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_length=shape[1], input_dim=shape[2]))
# output shape: (1, 1)
model.add(Dense(10,activation="tanh"))
model.add(Dense(10,activation="tanh"))
model.add(Dense(10,activation="tanh"))
model.add(Dense(10,activation="tanh"))
model.add(Dense(1,activation="linear"))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
model.summary()
```

And I migrate it to the Pytorch framework,

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, output_dim,bilstm=False):

    super(LSTM, self).__init__()
    self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.isBi = bilstm
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, batch_first=True,bidirectional=bilstm).double()
    # for name, param in self.lstm.named_parameters():
    #     if name.startswith("weight"):
    #         nn.init.orthogonal_(param)
    #     else:
    #         pass
   
    self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(hidden_dim, 10).double(),nn.Tanh())
    self.final_layer1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(10,10).double(),nn.Tanh())
    self.final_layer2 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(10,10).double(),nn.Tanh())
    self.final_layer3 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(10,10).double(),nn.Tanh())
    self.final_layer4 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(10,output_dim).double())

def forward(self, x):
    out, (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x)
    out = out[:, -1, :]
    out = self.fc1(out) 
    out = self.final_layer1(out)
    out = self.final_layer2(out)
    out = self.final_layer3(out)
    out = self.final_layer4(out)
    return out
```

The result is really bad. I was wondering if the initializing methods/activation functions used in Keras are different from the one I used in Pytorch(Keras seems to be using hard_sigmoid where Pytorch uses sigmoid?).

Would really appreciate it if somebody could help me with this problem!

**UPDATED**
My training code in Pytorch.

```
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
model = LSTM(input_dim,hidden_dim,num_layers,output_dim,bilstm)
model = model.cuda()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.001)
for epoch in range(1,epoch_number+1):
    model.train()
    iteration = 0
    for i,data in enumerate(train_loader):
        dat, label = data
        dat =  dat.double()
        label =  label.double()
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            dat = dat.cuda()
            label = label.cuda()
        else:
    
            dat = Variable(dat)
            label = Variable(label)
        out = model(dat)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = criterion(out, label)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Comment: Please also provide how you train your model in Pytorch, because part of compiling and training in keras is handled through `model.compile()`. btw, you can use `hn` from `self.lstm` instead of `out[:, -1, :]`. Also, no need to `.double()` every layer, you can just `double()` an entire model

Comment: Thank you Proko, I've updated the training code above.